# apt install no longer works for kubernetes. snap install also fails

Tags: apt, snap, kubernetes

I've always installed kubernetes with `sudo apt install -y kubectl kubeadm kubelet`.  This now gives the message

```
No apt package "kubeadm", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install kubeadm"


No apt package "kubectl", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install kubectl"


No apt package "kubelet", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install kubelet"
```

Now if I do

```
sudo snap install kubectl --classic
sudo snap install kubeadm --classic
sudo snap install kubelet --classic
```

I get

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.27.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
W0517 14:44:01.250068 1034876 checks.go:1064] [preflight] WARNING: Couldn't create the interface used for talking to the container runtime: crictl is required by the container runtime: executable file not found in $PATH
    [WARNING FileExisting-ethtool]: ethtool not found in system path
    [WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
```

If I do `systemctl enable kubelet.service`

I get:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file kubelet.service does not exist.
```

What did Canonical do?  They've broken the install for kuberetes.

Does someone have a script that works with whatever Canonical has done?  I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error looks like you are missing crictl which is a part of https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/releases
You could try something like this to install it

```
   go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
```